# How to save an alias of an eval $(other_comand) command

Tags: environment-variables, alias, eval

I've been using `docker` for a while and there's a command I write each time I boot up my docker:

```bash
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

I know `eval` shouldn't be used unless necessary, but it's mentioned by the following:

`docker-machine env` outputs environment variables like this:

```bash
docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://<some_ip>:<some_port>"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/gableroux/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env)
```

`eval` grabs these and load them in my current session.

Now what if I'd like to have an alias like this:

```bash
alias dockereval="eval $(docker-machine env)"
```

Syntax is good, but the problem is when a dotfile (let's say `.zshrc` as an example), well the content of the `$()` is evaluated when registering the alias when you `source` that file.

```bash
which dockereval
```

Results in

```
dockerenv: aliased to eval
```

I tried a few things like:

```
alias dockereval="docker-machine env | eval"
alias dockereval="docker-machine env | /bin/bash"
alias dockereval="eval `docker-machine env`"
```

but none did work. 2nd one is probably because it's running in a different session, 3rd does the same as `$()` I guess

**Is there an other way to load these environment variables with an alias?**

Comment: Use single-ticks (`'`) in your alias definition so that the subshell is created and parsed each time you execute it rather then when you define the alias.

Comment: An alternate solution would be to use a function instead of an alias. I now prefer this to alias as I keep syntax highlighting and can split those magic shortcuts into multiple lines. 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enclose your alias in single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
alias dockereval='eval $(docker-machine env)'
```

Double quotes allow expansion of variable (in bash at least) while single quotes don't

Comment: you saved 1 minute form every terminal opens. +1